# Determining whether a point lies within the boundary of a physics body in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, game-physics, sprite-kit

I'm using Sprite Kit to create a game involving balloons. The balloon image is a long rectangle (dotted line) but I've defined a physics body around the balloon itself using a polygon (solid line). I'd like players to be able to "pop" the balloon. I'm using the following block of code to achieve this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];
    for (SKNode *node in nodes) {
        [node removeFromParent];
        SKAction *pop = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"pop.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
        [self runAction:pop];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when there are several balloons in the bunch, this method can result in a single tap popping multiple balloons. This is because the sprite images overlap (even though the physics bodies do not). There is also the undesired effect that a tap on the string will have the same effect as a tap on the balloon.

I have access to the coordinates of the touch point, but is it even possible to detect whether a point lies within the area defined by the physics body (as opposed to the node)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the physics world's `bodyAtPoint:` method:

```
SKPhysicsBody* body = [self.scene.physicsWorld bodyAtPoint:location];
```

Comment: This seemed like the best answer at first, but it looks like bodyAtPoint is still buggy. I'm experiencing some weird offsets and it looks like others are experiencing the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876932/sprite-kit-bodyatpoint-and-bodyinrect-return-incorrect-values

Answer (score 1):

bodyAtPoint is buggy but you have a working alternative.
You can create rays using baloon polygon path.

```
[self.physicsWorld enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart:rayStart end:rayEnd
     usingBlock:^(SKPhysicsBody *body, CGPoint point,CGVector normal, BOOL *stop) {

    if(body.categoryBitMask & baloonCategory){
        SKPhysicsBody *contactBody=body;
        CGPoint contactPoint=point;
        *stop=YES;
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked but wasn't able to find a way of checking whether a touch is made within the `physicsBody` of a sprite. I would suggest separating the string and the ballon sprites.

You can try any the following:

1. Using separate sprite nodes for the balloon and the string and connecting them using a `SKPhysicsJoint`.
2. Subclass `SKSpriteNode` and add two sprites, i.e. the balloon and the string as children of the Sprite. Then u can check whether a touch made on the sprite is on the ballon or not.

Additionally for the multiple ballon pop problem, you can modify your code like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];

    //Instead of popping all nodes within the touch, pop only the first object.
    if ([nodes count] > 0)
    {
        SKNode *node = [nodes firstObject];
        [node removeFromParent];
        SKAction *pop = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"pop.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
        [self runAction:pop];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it still true that it's not possible to detect whether or not a touch is within a physics body?