# Swift Spritekit isometric map touch location

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, isometric

I've started doing a small swift / spritekit project to teach myself game dev.
It starts with an isometric map, which I managed to draw. 
But I'm having trouble getting a precise touch location on the different tiles of the map. 
It works, but is slightly out of place, and does not seem consistent.

Here are my functions :

```
class PlayScene: SKScene {

let map = SKNode()
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let origin = view.frame.origin
        let mapOrigin = CGPointMake(origin.x + self.frame.width / 4, origin.y - self.frame.height / 4)


        let mapConfig: Int[][] =

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

    drawMap(mapConfig, mapOrigin: mapOrigin)
}
```

With :

```
 func drawMap(mapConfig:Int[][], mapOrigin:CGPoint)
{
    let tileHeight:CGFloat = 25.5
    let numColumns:Int = 8
    let numRows:Int = 8

    var position = mapOrigin
    var column: Int = 0
    var row: Int = 0

    for column = 0; column < numColumns; column++
    {
        for row = 0; row < numRows; row++
        {
            position.x = mapOrigin.x + CGFloat(column) * tileHeight
            position.y = mapOrigin.y + CGFloat(row) * tileHeight
            let isoPosition = twoDToIso(position)
            placeTile(isoPosition, mapConfig: mapConfig[row][column])
        }
    }
    self.addChild(map)
}

func placeTile(position:CGPoint, mapConfig:Int)
{
 switch mapConfig
    {
    case 0:
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"grassTile")
        sprite.position = position
        sprite.setScale(0.1)
        sprite.name = "\(position)"
        self.map.addChild(sprite)
    case 1:
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"roadTile")
        sprite.position = position
        sprite.setScale(0.1)
        sprite.name = "\(position)"
        self.map.addChild(sprite)
    default:
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"roadTileLTR")
        sprite.position = position
        sprite.setScale(0.1)
        sprite.name = "\(position)"
        self.map.addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

And then I want to hide the tile I touch (for testing) :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    for touch: AnyObject in touches
    {
        let locationNode = touch.locationInNode(self)
        nodeAtPoint(locationNode).hidden = true
    }
}
```

But it does not always hide the correct tile.
So how should I tackle this ? Is my code fundamentally wrong (possible) ? Or do I need to convert the location to iso coordinates in some way ? Or play with the tiles bitmask ?

Thanks for your help in any case !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue with isometric map.

The problem is that the node you click on is bigger than displayed (it has transparent parts). See [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578564/detect-click-touch-on-isometric-texture) for a better explanation of the issue.

Here is how I solved it (sorry code is in Objective-C) :

1.Create a CGPathRef following the edges of the tile (tileSize being the size of the texture). This code is for regular isometric tiles, not hexagonal but the idea is the same.

```
// ObjC
-(CGPathRef)createTextureFrame:(CGSize)tileSize
{
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, -(self.tileSize.height / 2));
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, (self.tileSize.width / 2), 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, (self.tileSize.height / 2));
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, -(self.tileSize.width / 2), 0);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    return path;
}

// Swift
func createTextureFrame(tileSize:CGSize) -> CGPathRef {
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, -(self.tileSize.height / 2))
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, (self.tileSize.width / 2), 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, (self.tileSize.height / 2))
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -(self.tileSize.width / 2), 0)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
    return path
}
```

2.Create a function that checks if a given point is inside the CGPathRef (textureFrame).

```
// ObjC
-(BOOL)isPointOnNode:(CGPoint)point
{
    return CGPathContainsPoint(textureFrame, NULL, point, YES);
}

// Swift
func isPointOnNode(point:CGPoint) -> Bool {
    return CGPathContainsPoint(textureFrame, nil, point, YES)
}
```

3.For each touched nodes, check which textureFrame we're in.

```
// ObjC
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];
for (SKNode *node in nodes)
{
    CGPoint locationInNode = [touch locationInNode:node];
    if ([node isPointOnNode:locationInNode])
    {
        node.hidden = YES;
    }
}

// Swift
var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
var nodes = self.nodesAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self))
for node in nodes as [SKNode] {
    var locationInNode = touch.locationInNode(node)

    if node.isPointOnNode() {
        node.hidden = true
    }
}
```

I do not know if it's the best solution but it works great.
I hope it helps :)

**Edit :** Added Swift version of the code

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll try this soon, and if I can work it out, will post the Swift equivalent.

Comment: Since I posted this I started to learn Swift. I updated my answer ;)
I wrote that from memory and I cannot test it right now, so there may be some mistakes